# How to properly select tags in jqXHR returned by jQuery $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am building a barebones webapp in django with jQuery. I am running into an issue properly getting at HTML elements that are returned in jqXHR from a $.post call. $.post is called from a js function that bundles up some timestamp data and hits a django endpoint, which in return serves an HTML file that contains a couple <tbody> tags and a <div>, which are inserted into the main page by jQuery .replaceWith calls. The tangle I'm running into is that jQuery is able to access and handle the <tbody> elements just fine, but cannot locate the <div>. Code below has been synopsized a bit to save space.

#### js function that generates the post call and handles insertion to main page

```js
funciton getDbUpdate(){
    let _WaitTimes = JSON.stringify(compileWaitTimes());
    $.post("{% url 'checkForDbUpdate' %}",
        {_WaitTimes, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
        function(data, status){
            if (status!='nocontent'){
                const queueTableHTML = $(data).filter("#queueTableBody").html(); //works
                const archiveTableHTML = $(data).filter("#archiveTableBody").html(); //works
                const targetDivElet = $(data).filter("#targetDivElet").html(); //returns nothing
                $('#queueTable > tbody').replaceWith(queueTableHTML);
                $('#archiveTable > tbody').replaceWith(archiveTableHTML);
                $('#targetDivElet').replaceWith(targetDivElet)
            };
        );
};
```

#### django endpoint from views.py

```py
def checkForDbUpdate(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # --> do some database operations
        
        # return http 204 if nothing has changed between polls
        if ids_from_request==ids_from_model:
            response = HttpResponse()
            response.status_code=204
            return response
        template = loader.get_template('table.html')
        context = {
        'archived':archived,
        'unarchived:unarchived,
        'valueForDiv':valueForDiv
        }
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

#### HTML document returned by Django endpoint, to be processed by jQuery

```html
<tbody id="queueTableBody">
    {% for x in unarchived %}
        <tr>
            <td> value 1 </td>
            .
            .
            .
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>

<tbody id="archiveTableBody">
    {% for x in archived %}
        <tr>
            <td> value 1 </td>
            .
            .
            .
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>

<div id="targetDivElet">Value</div>
```

I tried various suggestions involving DOM readiness, but to little success. I was expecting jQuery to return the target <div> or at least its innerHTML, according to their docs [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#jqxhr-object) (see last example in the doc page). The result jQuery seems to actually present when looking at the whole $(data) object is as follows:

```
Object { 0: tbody#queueTableBody, 1: #text, 2: tbody#archiveTableBody, 3: #text, 4: tbody, 5: #text, length: 6 }
0: <tbody id="queueTableBody">
1: #text "\n\n\n"
2: <tbody id="archiveTableBody">
3: #text "\n"
4: <tbody>
5: #text "\n\n\n"
length: 6
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would first be suspicioud of the Data you are sending in your Post. When I see `{_WaitTimes, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'}`, I would be concerned that this does not contain all the correct syntax.

Comment: If the HTML being returned is what you posted, then something is not being generated correctly. You should be able to interact with the HTML as is, `const queueTableHTML = $("#queueTableBody", data).children();`

Comment: @Twisty , Thanks for your reply. The HTML I posted is the pre-render template, once anything comes or goes from django, anything of the form `{{ variable }}` or `{% routine %}` is being properly handled by the templating engine. The baffling thing is that the HTML , post-render, is well-formed (dumped the raw `data` object, sans jQuery parsing, as a string to the console and it's exactly as expected) and jQuery is able to process the `<tbody>` parts in the callback, but seems to parse `<div>` tags as just being text.

Comment: Ultimately, this whole exercise was to get a path string back from the server (was to be packed inside the `<div>`), and I was able to find another route by creating an additional django endpoint that returns a JSON object with the desired data. The new endpoint gets queried by a `$.get` call inside the `if (status != 'nocontent'){...}` clause, and is working as desired, so I functionally have a fix, but am still curious as to why jQuery seemed to only be willing to grab the `<tbody>` objects in the original setup.